# the browser console always shows index.js:21

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

This is a bug in Vue or in Bootstrap I'm not sure

I am developing in *Vue* and *Laravel*. when logging on browser console, the browser always shows that the location of *console.log* is in `index.js:21`.

and when I click on the index.js it takes me to this place:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import Alert from './alert'
import Button from './button'
import Carousel from './carousel'
import Collapse from './collapse'
import Dropdown from './dropdown'
import Modal from './modal'
import Popover from './popover'
import Scrollspy from './scrollspy'
import Tab from './tab'
import Tooltip from './tooltip'
import Util from './util'

/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Bootstrap (v4.1.3): index.js
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

(($) => {
  if (typeof $ === 'undefined') {
    throw new TypeError('Bootstrap\'s JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap\'s JavaScript.')
  }

  const version = $.fn.jquery.split(' ')[0].split('.')
  const minMajor = 1
  const ltMajor = 2
  const minMinor = 9
  const minPatch = 1
  const maxMajor = 4

  if (version[0] < ltMajor && version[1] < minMinor || version[0] === minMajor && version[1] === minMinor && version[2] < minPatch || version[0] >= maxMajor) {
    throw new Error('Bootstrap\'s JavaScript requires at least jQuery v1.9.1 but less than v4.0.0')
  }
})($)

export {
  Util,
  Alert,
  Button,
  Carousel,
  Collapse,
  Dropdown,
  Modal,
  Popover,
  Scrollspy,
  Tab,
  Tooltip
}
```

The browser underlines the opening parenthesis "("(%) => {
The underline part is put in string literals

```
(($) => {
  if (typeof $ === 'undefined') {
    throw new TypeError('Bootstrap\'s JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap\'s JavaScript.')
  }
```

[A snapshot of the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1sp9.png)

[The browser underlining. I think the issue happens there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDqFg.png)

Comment: Please read my question again. I really looked in StackOverflow and I didn't find anything similar

Comment: There are at least 2 possible reasons for not showing correct line of code in console. 1. Which is most likely your case - invalid configuration in webpack or inaccessible sourcemaps. 2. Some libraries or custom implementation overwrites `console.log` and as a result it is always displayed as a source of log.